# Android MapFragment scale

Tags: android, google-maps

How can I create a scale bar showing relative distance using an Android MapFragment? I know how to do it using overlays with a MapView but I can't work out how to do it in a MapFragment.

Comment: post the code for the mapview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils.

They have `Spherical geometry` function that you can use `computeDistance, computeHeading, computeArea`. Start with their demo first.